# imagemagick composite with min width but varying height

Tags: imagemagick

I want to have a background image with another image composited over top to the bottom edge. The final image will have maximum width (say, 1000px, but may be less). The composited image can shrink in width but always needs to be at the bottom. I can't seem to find a way get this all done in one command with imagemagick.

Here is some dummy images as an example.

Image to composite over the background:
[image: composite image]

Here are two examples of end products I want:
[image: wide-ish]
This one is 960px wide, but yet the composited image is flush bottom and left/right edge.

[image: narrow]
This one is quite narrow, but the composited image has shrunk to make it flush bottom/left/right.

Since the images may vary in size and aspect ratio, I'd rather not have to do some sort of external calculation to scale and position the composited image. I feel like this should be possible within imagemagick, right?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest to identify the width of background image beforehand.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Get background width
WIDTH=`convert background.jpg -format "%w" info:`
# Apply composite
convert background.jpg \
        \( arrows.png -resize "${WIDTH}x" \) \
        -alpha set \
        -gravity South \
        -compose ATop \
        -composite output.png
```

The `\( arrows.png -resize "${WIDTH}x" \)` is a subprocess for matching widths, and `-gravity South` will keep the arrows anchored to the bottom.

[image: rose:]
[image: logo:]
[image: wizard:]